# Need correct with recurrence in google calendar api java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, icalendar, rfc5545

Is it correct recurrence rule for icalendar?

```
RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD:19960403T020000Z/19960403T040000Z,19960404T010000Z/PT3H
```

When i set this string in event in google calendar via api i get event only with start from this.

Thats what i have:

```
       RDATE;TZID=America/New_York:19960403T020000Z

DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2020-12-16T09:00:00");
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Europe/Minsk");
    event.setStart(start);
```

it's a java code where i create the main event:

```
Event event = new Event()
            .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
            .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
            .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");
    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2020-12-16T17:00:00");
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Europe/Minsk");
    event.setEnd(end);
```

Comment: What is the final result you are trying to achieve? (For example: Having a monday to friday, and from 9 to 12 event; setting 3 events on dates X, Y, Z; etc.)

Comment: i want to set different duration but every time i have one time, which set in main event. For example:i set in main event time 20201223T140000 and duration is 2H and want to set rucurrence like this 20201224T102000/20201224T112000. When i send this string to google i had 20201224T102000/20201224T122000 - duration is 2H

Comment: Maybe the problem is in other parts of the request like the starting or the ending date. Could you please add them to the question? I'd also try to use the period definition using a duration: `RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD:20201224T102000Z/PT2H`

Comment: i add java code where i create main event. And i tried to use period like RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD:20201224T102000Z/PT2H - it's doesn't work, because used only start date from this rule

Comment: Have you tried creating the recurrent event as mentioned in the example for Java here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#creating_recurring_events ?

Comment: yes, i tried and this example works, but it's not a good solution in my case. In my case i need something like "RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD:20201224T102000Z/PT2H", but it's not work

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand you question still. Can you point from the [RFC 5545](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545) what you are trying to replicate with Google Calendar API?

Comment: 3.8.5.2.  Recurrence Date-Times.   I need this "RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD:19960403T020000Z/19960403T040000Z,
        19960404T010000Z/PT3H